# Compute its limit.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinations

I input this on Wolfram alpha.
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n!}{n!n!}p^n(1-p)^n$ when $p\in(0,1)$ and $p\neq\frac{1}{2}$.
The result is $\frac{1-\sqrt{(2p-1)^2}}{\sqrt{(2p-1)^2}}$
I don't know how to get this value.

Comment: I suppose you mean $(2n)!$ as opposed to $2(n!)$, right?

Comment: $$\frac{1-\sqrt{(2p-1)^2}}{\sqrt{(2p-1)^2}}=\frac{2p}{1-2p}$$

Comment: This is a simple [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using generating function for [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties),  i.e.
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4x}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}x^n$$
and putting $\displaystyle x =  p(1-p)$ gives 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 4p(1-p)}} - 1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2p - 1)^2}} - 1$$

which simplifies to the result.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the partial summation involves the beta function $$\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{2n!}{n!n!}p^n(1-p)^n=-1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-2 p)^2}}-\frac{\Gamma \left(m+\frac{3}{2}\right) B_{-4 (p-1)
   p}\left(m+1,\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } \sqrt{(2 p-1)^2} \Gamma
   (m+1)}$$ For an infinite value of $m$, you get your result which simplifies a lot as Norbert showed.

Comment: thanks. the third term of RHS seems complicated.